# Group by in sql

Tags: sql

I am a SQL rookie. I am writing a query:

```
SELECT iif([Cancellation Date] is NULL, 'Not Cancelled', 'Cancelled') as Status,
       SUM(Loss) as [Total Loss]
from INSURANCE_DATA
GROUP by Status;
```

So basically I want to aggregate the losses by the policy status. 
This query is unable to run, because I am grouping by a new variable generated in this very query?

I can write another query based on this one to have what I want, but is there any intriguing solution enabling me to get it done in one query?

Comment: Just `group by iif([Cancellation Date] is NULL, 'Not Cancelled', 'Cancelled')`

Comment: What version of SQL (MS Access?) What is the actual error?

Comment: Are you using MS-Access or a different DBMS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried grouping by the expression you are declaring in the select rather than referring to it's alias?

e.g.

```
SELECT iif([Cancellation Date] is NULL, 'Not Cancelled', 'Cancelled') as Status,
SUM(Loss) as [Total Loss] from INSURANCE_DATA GROUP BY iif([Cancellation Date] is NULL,
'Not Cancelled', 'Cancelled');
```

Dan

Comment: Happy to help. Any chance you could accept one of our answers please?

Comment: You'll need to click the tick next to the answer you found most useful. Check out the tour [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 1):

You're right, you can't use the alias in the group by. But if you make your group by value...

```
GROUP BY [Cancellation Date] is NULL
```

Then it's effectively the same thing.

Comment: What is `DESC` doing there? Does Access indeed accept `ASC` or `DESC` in `GROUP BY`?

Comment: Hahaha not sure. I guess I thought I was writing an order by... Thanks for the catch! I'll remove it.